# Extracting subscription name when the cmdlets doesnt return it or how to use a hash table or function to return subscription name

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-resource-manager

I have written a PowerShell script that will generate a report of all groups assigned to users in azure, the last section is a group by report of all groups in each subscription and the total number of users assigned to such groups. Where I have become stuck is the subscription ID, I want to replace the ID with the subscription name and where I have created a custom object, if I can append the subscription name to it rather than the ID, this will allow me to use `group-object` and it means the work to get the subscription name only needs to be done once. It is much easier for users of the report to get the subscription name as this is easier to read as part of the report and also the `group-object` at the end of the script.

What have I done ?

From my research, a hash table is the way to go. what I effectively need is a lookup or a function where if I provide the subscription ID, it returns the subscription name. Then use that in the first report which generates a csv and also on the group-object section.

I have tried the hash here, but unsure about the implementation

```
$subscription_hash = @{}
$subscription_hash = Get-Azsubscription | Select-Object Id, Name
```

The full code can be found below.

```
# Set the output CSV file path
$outputFilePath = "C:\output\Report.csv"

# Create an empty array to store the results
$all_results = @()


# Function to retrieve role assignments for a subscription
function Get-RoleAssignmentsForSubscription {
    param (
        [string]$subscriptionId
    )

    try {   
        $all_results2 = @()
        $roleAssignments = Get-AzRoleAssignment -Scope "/subscriptions/$subscriptionId"
        foreach ($assignment in $roleAssignments) {

            if ($null -ne $assignment.DisplayName  -or $null -ne $assignment.SignInName ){
                $result_object = New-Object PSObject
                Add-Member -inputObject $result_object -memberType NoteProperty -name "Subscription" -value $subscriptionId
                Add-Member -inputObject $result_object -memberType NoteProperty -name "Subscription_Name" -value "Unknown"
                Add-Member -inputObject $result_object -memberType NoteProperty -name "Display Name" -value $assignment.DisplayName
                Add-Member -inputObject $result_object -memberType NoteProperty -name "SignIn Name" -value $assignment.SignInName
                Add-Member -inputObject $result_object -memberType NoteProperty -name "Object Type" -value $assignment.ObjectType
                Add-Member -inputObject $result_object -memberType NoteProperty -name "Object ID" -value $assignment.ObjectId
                Add-Member -inputObject $result_object -memberType NoteProperty -name "assignment" -value $assignment.RoleDefinitionName
                Add-Member -inputObject $result_object -memberType NoteProperty -name "RoleDefinition ID" -value $assignment.RoleDefinitionId
                Add-Member -inputObject $result_object -memberType NoteProperty -name "Scope" -value $assignment.Scope
                Add-Member -inputObject $result_object -memberType NoteProperty -name "Description" -value $assignment.Description
                Add-Member -inputObject $result_object -memberType NoteProperty -name "CanDelegate" -value $assignment.CanDelegate
            }

            $all_results2 += $result_object

            }

            Write-Output $all_results2
            return $all_results2
    }
    catch {
        Write-Host "Error retrieving role assignments for subscription $subscriptionId -Error detail $_"
    }
}

# Get all subscriptions in the Azure account
$subscriptions = Get-AzSubscription

# Loop through each subscription
foreach ($subscription in $subscriptions) {
    $subscriptionId = $subscription.Id
    $all_results_get_assignment =  Get-RoleAssignmentsForSubscription -subscriptionId $subscriptionId
    $all_results += $all_results_get_assignment
}

# Export the results to a CSV file

Write-Host "Script execution completed. Results exported to $outputFilePath."
# $all_results | Export-Csv -Path $outputFilePath -NoTypeInformation



$subscription_hash = @{}
$subscription_hash = Get-Azsubscription | Select-Object Id, Name

#breakdown using subscription ID
$all_results | Group-Object -Property assignment, subscription | Select-Object subscription,Name, Count | sort Count -Descending


$all_results | Group-Object -Property assignment, subscription | Select-Object $subscription_hash[subscription],Name, Count | sort Count -Descending
```

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking to do is *join* the objects outputted by `Get-AzSubscription` with each object outputted by `Get-AzRoleAssignment` and all your code can be reduced to this:

```bash
Get-AzSubscription | ForEach-Object {
    foreach ($assignment in Get-AzRoleAssignment -Scope "/subscriptions/$($_.Id)") {
        if ($assignment.DisplayName -or $assignment.SignInName) {
            [pscustomobject]@{
                'Subscription'      = $_.Id
                'Subscription_Name' = $_.Name
                'Display Name'      = $assignment.DisplayName
                'SignIn Name'       = $assignment.SignInName
                'Object Type'       = $assignment.ObjectType
                'Object ID'         = $assignment.ObjectId
                'assignment'        = $assignment.RoleDefinitionName
                'RoleDefinition ID' = $assignment.RoleDefinitionId
                'Scope'             = $assignment.Scope
                'Description'       = $assignment.Description
                'CanDelegate'       = $assignment.CanDelegate
            }
        }
    }
} | Export-Csv 'C:\output\Report.csv' -NoTypeInformation
```

The `Get-RoleAssignmentsForSubscription` is inefficient and is not needed, it's just making things harder for you.

Comment: Thanks @Santiago Squarzon for the solution, it works well. I do have 2 questions. I cannot get `group-object` to work if I save the output onto a variable called $all_data, If I now try to run `$all_data | Group-Object -Property Subscription_Name, assignment | Select-Object Subscription_Name, assignment, Count | sort Count -Descending` The values of Subscription_Name and assignment are blank. Lastly, as I have saved the output into a variable, I will like to create a new field called `assigned_object` this should have either `Display_Name` if its not null or `Signin Name` if not null.